# Place elements under others in Linear Layout inside Constraint Layout

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to place a set of elements in a column, inside my LinearLayout. The problem is that it doesn't recognize instruction like "layout_below" (it says it is invalide): This is the result:
[image]

The result I'm expecting is the first TextView and Spinner on the first line, The "Release" TextView and the EditText on the second line and the other three elements on the third line. This is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="49dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="49dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="49dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="49dp"
        android:text="Search"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_20ssp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search_field"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/search_layout"
        android:ems="10"
        android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_bold"
        android:hint="Search here"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/search_btn"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/search_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/cardview_shadow_end_color"
        android:paddingTop="17dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/checkbox_adv"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/search_field"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/search_button" />


    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox_adv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Advanced search"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_30sdp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/hiddenTab"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/search_btn"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/search_field"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/search_field" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/hiddenTab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_7sdp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/popular_rc_view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/search_btn"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/search_field"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/checkbox_adv"
        tools:visibility="visible">

        <!-- LINE 1 -->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textGenre"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Genre:"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textAlignment="gravity" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinnerGenre"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:entries="@array/genre_list" />

        <!-- END OF LINE 1 -->

        <!-- LINE 2 -->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textYear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Release:"
            android:layout_below="@+id/genresTextView"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textAlignment="gravity" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/releaseYear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <!-- END OF LINE 2 -->

        <!-- LINE 3 -->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textVote"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Rating:"
            android:layout_below="@+id/genresTextView"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textAlignment="gravity" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinnerOperator"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:entries="@array/operator_list" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinnerVote"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:entries="@array/vote_list" />

        <!-- END OF LINE 3 -->

    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/popular_rc_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/hiddenTab" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/recent_icon"
        android:text="Most Recent"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/design_default_color_on_primary"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/fab2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1"
        app:maxImageSize="35dp"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/rated_icon"
        android:text="Most Rated"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/design_default_color_background"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/fab1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1"
        app:maxImageSize="35dp"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/pop_icon"
        android:text="Most Popular"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/design_default_color_background"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/fab"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1"
        app:maxImageSize="35dp"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/filter"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1"
        app:maxImageSize="35dp"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute `android:layout_below` isn't recognized because it's an attribute of `RelativeLayout`, `LinearLayout` hasn't that kind of attribute.

To obtain your desired behavior, `LinearLayout` isn't the right `ViewGroup` for you since it allows only to stack subviews horizontally or vertically, not to mix an horizontal arrangement and a vertical one.

You should use `ConstraintLayout` (better) or `RelativeLayout` (worse) to obtain that behavior.

Furthermore, since your parent is already a `ConstraintLayout` you don't need the nested `ViewGroup` `hiddenTab` to arrange the views in that position. If `hiddenTab` was simply added to control its visibility, remember that you can use the `ContraintLayout`'s [`Group`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/Group) to control it.